# Python error (return outside function) while running the module after the if statement

Tags: python, function, return

```
def report_status(scheduled_time,estimated_time):
    '''(number, number) -> str
    Return the flight status (on time, early , delayed) for a flight that was scheduled to
    arrive at scheduled_time but is now estimated to arrive at estimated_time.
pre-condition: 0.0<= scheduled_time < 24 ; 0.0<= estimated_time < 24
>>> report_status(14.3,14.3)
'on time'
>>> report_status(12.5,11.5)
'early'
>>> report_status(9.0,9.2)
'delayed'
'''
if scheduled_time == estimated_time:
   return'on time'
elif scheduled_time > estimated_time:
    return 'early'
else:
    return 'delayed'
```

Comment: Don't just paste a block of code at us; tell us what's wrong, post the full stack trace if you have one, and ask us a question.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong. The way you have it, none of the code is inside the function. Indent everything one level from 'pre-condition' onwards.

Comment: Also check that indentation is obtained by either spaces or tabs, but not both.